# Can XStream be configured to have bi-drectional (parent/child) references?

Tags: java, xstream

I'm using XStream to load a file structured like this:

```
<parent>
  <child/>
  <child/>
</parent>
```

Into a class like this:

```
public class Parent(){
 private List<Child> children;
}

public class Child { 
 private Parent parent; 
}
```

I would like to be able to do this: `parent.getChildren().get(0).getParent()`

I would like to be able to use the XML as it sits. I know I can add references to the parent under children, but that seems very redundant. I know the childs parent because of its XML structure.

Does XStream support this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes Xstream supports back-links to avoid circular references. It does this by default, but its arguable whether a message that required this is really a suitable one. Its fine for just chucking some data over the network, but isn't really a "message", more a serialized object.

Your child objects will need to have a "pointer" to the parent.

Comment: I agree with your assesment that this may not be a good idea, I'm operating under some outside constraints though. So `public class Child { private Parent parent; }`. Will XStream populate this automagically? What XStream annotation or config do I need to set up to handle this?

Comment: well - if the reference is set when you marshal the object it will be set when you unmarshal it. IIRC it just happens. Did you try it? Thats the way i normally see if they work!

Comment: it doesn't take long: System.out.println(new XStream().toXML(parent));

Comment: The XML I'm serializing is fixed in a format similar to the example I gave. So would I be forced to reformat it to `<parent id="blah"><child><parent id="blah"/><child><parent>`? That seems redundant, the parent should be definable by its position.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `readResolve` in the parent to set the backreferences.  This will be called in the same way as standard library serialization according to the XStream FAQ here: http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#Serialization_initialize_transient

When `readResolve` is called, the `Parent` and all its children will have been deserialized already, so you can set the backreference at that time.

```
public class Parent {
  private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
  private Object readResolve() {
    for( Child child: children ) {
      child.setParent(this);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to consider using something other than XStream, then [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) handles bi-directional properties easily with [@XmlInverseReference](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html) (I'm the MOXy tech lead).

Your object model would be mapped as:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Parent {

    private List<Child> children;

    @XmlElement(name="child")
    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

and (note the use of @XmlInverseReference on the parent property):

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;

public class Child {

    private Parent parent;

    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="children")
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

The demo code would look like (input.xml refers to the XML from your question):

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Parent parent = (Parent) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));

        for(Child child : parent.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.getParent());
        }
    }

}
```

To specify MOXy as the JAXB implementation you need to include a file called jaxb.properties in the same package as your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Below is a link to my comparison of JAXB and XStream:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: Your answer is probably a better path, but this project is locked in to XStream.